# should wiki references be allowed?

Tags: discussion, references

I think it is very important that we allow only Manga references in the answers to any questions. I think that wiki references tend to loose context of the situation where the information came from. This may even lead to pple starting to answer with really unreliable sources as references and this might get the site credibility to decline. Thus, I think all the references should be from Manga/anime and not wikis

But all in all, the above is all my own opinion.

Thus, I ask you:

should wiki references be allowed?

Comment: Isn't the reason of making a wiki to have a reliable source? So if the wiki *is* reliable, why not? It's the purpose of the wiki, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: a wiki may be reliable but it just answers a lot more related questions when the chapter reference is provided. All that is missed when a wiki reference is provided that does not included chapter references

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing wrong with referencing any source you may find, and think that is credible. Whether you, the OP, accepts it as one, is your business.

If you wish for manga reference, ask the answerer politely in the comments to include them. If he does not oblige, do not accept his answer. It's as simple as that.

The wiki, from which the reference in question is taken, is (in my eyes) a relatively credible source, as it's regularly updated and maintained.

Comment: And the wiki often presents manga references itself.

Comment: and how do innocent bystanders benefit from this? I have'nt asked the question but I want to know where the info came from. What do I do?

Comment: @MozenRath: The information came from the wiki. Which by itself is a reliable source of information. Often, the wiki itself contains reference to manga chapter/pages too.

Comment: you don't understand, wiki's state facts plainly many a times and in those situations it gets really difficult to trust them. I think manga references are most satiable for anybody

Comment: I mean  `senju hashirama died naming is bro as the next hokage` but where hell did they say that in the manga. Ok wiki may be right but when was that revealed?

Comment: @MozenRath It's mentioned in the [first Naruto databook](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rin_no_Sho). The wiki usually cite the source of relevant information such as this. That is how you can factcheck the references to make sure they are accurate.

Comment: ok so are you saying that most of them have references planted on the links?

Answer (score 4):

I personally think they are Ok. Consider the following:

- Wikis are collaboratively edited, so they usually will not allow wrong data to be posted
- most wikis have their own references to the sources (chapters/episodes)
- It may take **way too long** to find references yourself. Sometimes I remember that something has happened, but can't remember in what exact chapter/episode did it happen. In this case, it's obviously impossible to recheck all of the chapters or episodes.
- If the poster of the question accepts the answer, it means that he/she is satisfied, no matter what the sources were.
- If you want exact references in a question you ask, feel free to explicitly state it, and not to accept any answers without them.
- If you think some answer is missing references, you can always leave a comment asking the author to add the.

Comment: y not paste the chapter no instead of the wiki in the answer?

Comment: @MozenRath, if the reference is there, there is no reason not to paste it. But referencing the wiki too would be fair, I think.

Comment: Ohhk based on all the answers I have come realize the importance of wiki references, BUT only the wiki references that include chapter references would make sense. Then comes the problem of differentiating the two....

Comment: @MozenRath, it's more about people than wikis. For example if I see that a wiki is missing a reference, i try to find it myself. Some people might do that too, and some will just post a wiki reference and leave it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have a reference from the original source, a wiki reference is useful because it can be directly linked to (for verification and to provide extra background). In contrast, there's no reliable way to hyperlink to a specific point in a cartoon.

Comment: that is not necessarily true. It all depends on the the question. I do agree that some times it might happen that a wiki proves to be a better reference. but even during that situation, without the references from original chapters, it makesd me wonder how and when that particular fact was revealed. Forgive me If you think am asking for too much...

Comment: @MozenRath: How do you expect to hyperlink it?

Comment: well you don't, all readers know where they their manga's from and should have access to them. That is the problem of the OP. I don't think you can ask a question without reading the manga